# How do you write the types for a function in-place destructuring in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, destructuring

A user will pass an `hisObject` to `myFn`. See this simple example:

```
type HisType = { a:string, b:number };

function myFn( { a:string, b:number } = hisObject): void {
  console.log(a,b);
}
```

But could we include that `hisObject` is of type `HisType` to avoid errors?

How do you write the types for a function in-place destructuring in TypeScript?

Comment: Where is `hisObject` and `HisType` defined?

Comment: @Dai elsewhere, but I can include a definition

Comment: Yes. Please post code that can be copied+pasted into TS Playgrounds without any errors.

Comment: `HisObject` and `hisObject` are different identifiers - and neither are `HisType`.

Comment: @Dai just realized how to do it, thanks for suggesting using the playground =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a default argument:

```
function myFn({ a, b }: HisType): void {
  console.log(a, b);
}
```

With a default argument (`hisObject` points to the default value):

```
// This exists earlier in the program
const hisObject: HisType = /* ... */;

function myFn({ a, b }: HisType = hisObject): void {
  console.log(a, b);
}
```